# How can I troubleshoot enqueue in general and loading Google fonts specifically?

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, fonts

I have this code straight out of one of default themes to load two Google fonts, except I changed the function name. The fonts are not loading, sans serif font shows instead. How do I troubleshoot this?

```
//add Google fonts

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sg_add_google_fonts' );

function sg_add_google_fonts() {

 $query_args = array(
   'family' => 'Dosis:400,600,700|Roboto:400,400italic,700,700italic'
 );

 wp_register_style( 
   'google-fonts', 
   add_query_arg( $query_args, '//fonts.googleapis.com/css' ), 
   array(), 
   null 
 );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts' );

}
```

in style.css

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #3c3c3c;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #3c3c3c;
}
```

I actually never was able to enqueue anything in WP - scripts, style sheets, nothing, and ended up hardcoding URLs in the header. I would like to find out a general method how to find out what's not working while using enqueue. Is there some kind of an error message I can have output?

Thank you!

Comment: What theme are you using? Does it call `wp_head()` within the `head` tag? Have you looked at the page source to verify if the style and script tags are there or not?

Comment: it's a custom theme, yes, the problem was with wp_head. I now understand that wp_enqueue_scripts prints out script tags! :). If you put this as an answer I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Please try it out.Thanks

```
    function tf_add_google_fonts() {wp_enqueue_style( 'tf-google-fonts', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,700,300', false ); 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tf_add_google_fonts' );
```